# How to pass a html element property/attribute in the event handler in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a list of data which i display in the html template this way.

```
<div>
   <a (click)='onClick(this)' someproperty='test'></a>
   <a (click)='onClick(this)' someproperty='test'></a>
   <a (click)='onClick(this)' someproperty='test'></a>
   <a (click)='onClick(this)' someproperty='test'></a>
</div>
```

I want to change one property dynamically whenever i click an item. However, Angular is showing the object as undefined.

here is my Component:

```
declare var $:any;
export class MyComponent {
  onClick(someobject): void {
    $(someobject).attr('someproperty','dontTest');//console shows "Undefined"

  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try below,

```
 <a (click)='onClick($event)' someproperty='test'>click me</a>

 onClick(someobject): void {
    someobject.target.attributes['someproperty'].value = "donttest";
    console.log(someobject.target.attributes['someproperty'].value);
  }
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/RwkEuLPTrYjTPZcU0nv6?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: the solution to pass the $event was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it all by template

See [Attribute Binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#attribute-binding) documentation.

```
<div>
   <a (click)="val1 = 'new val 1'" [attr.someproperty]="val1">Link 1</a>
   <a (click)="val2 = 'new val 2'" [attr.someproperty]="val2">Link 2</a>
   <a (click)="val3 = 'new val 3'" [attr.someproperty]="val3">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Here the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4DzYveYeOzStQDsLZEdl?p=preview)

Just inspect the links and click on it to see **someproperty** changing.

Comment: awesome. thanks Noemi. It worked in plunker. I'll implement it in my code now and will get back.

Comment: Great :) Do not forget to validate the answer if it answered your need.